# Return column title of the max value in the row in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, max, match

I have a 2 row table with 6 column. The first column have titles and the second row in each column the result of a sum.
When I use the `=MAX(A2:F2)` it returns the biggest value, But when using `=MATCH(MAX(A2:F2),A1:F1,0)` doesn't return the text.
What is the correct way to do this in Excel?

Comment: Following answer should work. If need help yet, let us know by comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need this, which uses INDEX to find the corresponding entry in A1:F1 to the max in A2:F2

```
=INDEX(A1:F1,MATCH(MAX(A2:F2),A2:F2,0))
```

Comment: what if I don't have contiguous cells? For e.g I have A => C and E and F columns.